# C Function that returns number of X, Y, Z characters in a string and how to call it?

Tags: c

I need some help solving this. I am pretty new to C so this is giving me some trouble. I can do it fine with 3 functions that each return 1 value like this:

```
int cnt(char x, char *s) {
    int b=0;

    while(*s)
    {
        if(*s++== x) b++;
    }

    return b;
}
```

I do 3 of those and then just call them separately in main. The thing is I wanna do it with just one function. I have a general idea on how the function would work, but I have no idea how to call it. Would really be thankful for a solution to my little problem.

Comment: I would call this `findCharacter`. `cnt` is prone to mis-typing (and I dare not guess what auto-correct would make of it), and it looks to me more like a variable name than a function.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep your functions generic, even if you want them to perform specialized tasks. Written in modern C, such a function could look like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void count_chars (const char*  str, 
                  const char*  keys,
                  size_t       keys_length,
                  size_t       result[keys_length])
{
  memset(result, 0, sizeof(size_t)*keys_length);


  str = (const char*) strpbrk(str, keys);

  while(str != NULL)
  {
    for(size_t i=0; i<keys_length; i++) 
    {
      if(*str == keys[i])
      {
        result[i]++;
        break;
      }
    }

    str++;
    str = (const char*) strpbrk(str, keys);
  }
}


int main()
{
  const char str[] = "xyxyz";
  const char SEARCH_KEYS[] = "xyz"
  size_t length = strlen(SEARCH_KEYS);
  size_t result[length];

  count_chars(str, SEARCH_KEYS, length, result);

  printf("X: %zu\n", result[0]);
  printf("Y: %zu\n", result[1]);
  printf("Z: %zu\n", result[2]);
}
```

Comment: In `main`, should not the `result` array be the length of the keys isntead of the original string? (If you make the `keys` parameter a separate string, you can count its length and put the output printfs in a loop as well.)

Comment: The OP claimed to be learning C, throwing code at him without a bit of explanation about it won't really be helping IMO.

Comment: Minor: `"%u"` --> `"%zu"`.

Comment: @Jongware Indeed, thanks for spotting. I haven't tried this code. Fixed

Comment: @Chnossos Apart from the somewhat exotic strpbrk function, I believe the code speaks for itself. And nope, it doesn't mean "strip then bork" :) Google "C strpbrk".

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a pointer to an array of `3` `int`s (all  elements initialized to `0`) to your function and then store all of the three results in that array. Do not forget to change the return type of function to `void`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cnt(char x, char y, char z,  char *s, int *num) {
    while(*s)
    {
        if(*s == x)      num[0]++;
        else if(*s == y) num[1]++;
        else if(*s == z) num[2]++;
        s++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "asdafdssasadsadsa";
    int num[3] = {0};
    cnt('a', 's', 'd', s, num);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d\n", num[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This program will work only for three key characters. You can further improve this program to generalize.

Comment: That `i` business is the strangest in a while.

Comment: You are incrementing `s` in all conditions. Please fix that. This may also cause buffer overrun.

Comment: @unwind; Its just a rough idea :). `*num`, `*(num+1)`, `*(num+2)` would be more complicated for beginner.

Comment: Well, I think the point is you don't need i. num[0]++, num[1]++ and num[2]++

Comment: @haccks See nos comment for the obvious way, using literal indices only.

Comment: if you don't want to return something (like `num[0]+num[1]+num[2]`), change the function to be void

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt; That's what happens when you try to post a code without testing it. I suggested OP for that but...

Comment: Okay, and how would I go about calling all 3 results in main? Sorry for the dumb questions i am just a bit confused. :)

Comment: @nos; why? I do not understand.

Comment: He's saying that you've written a hard-coded function for one specific purpose, so you don't need the `i` variable.

Comment: @Lundin; Oh. Removed that.